# Magnific Popup shows scrollbar in front of lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magnific-popup

so I've been using Magnific Popup to display content through lightboxes.

At first I had the problem of the scrollbar disappearing and the content behind the lightbox moving to the right.

So I added
        html { overflow-y: scroll; }
and now the scrollbar stays visible and there's no movement to the right.

Trouble is, the scrollbar is visible above the lightbox, which I find undesirable.

You can see the problem here in a streamlined version of the page (click on the placeholder):
http://test.ilgufoblu.net/lab/prova.html

No idea how to fix this, if it's even fixable.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, if I add `margin: 0;` (which you can recreate visually with padding) to `body` and remove the `overflow-y: scroll` from `html` (or replace it with `auto`), I believe it behaves as desired.  Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/523mcv1k/

Comment: Yeah that works. I see now that the page version is too streamlined actually, since it still doesn't work on the original page which is more complex. Guess I'll have to post a new question. Thanks.

Comment: I think in your new code, to get things to "work" (i.e. avoid the double scrollbar and avoid the movement to the right), you'd have to remove the `overflow-y: scroll` from `html`, and, on the open callback, add `padding-right: 17px` and `overflow: hidden` to `body`, then remove those stylings on the close callback (probably easiest/cleanest by adding/removing a class to `html` on the callbacks, I would think).

Comment: That's a very good point. But is the scrollbar 17px wide on all major browsers? Let me check that out.

Comment: More or less. I think it's less than 17 on Safari.

Comment: What I don't get is why with other Lightbox plugins the scrollbar stays below the modal windows.

Comment: IIRC the 17px margin is added by Magnific on open, so that's just the value I just used to counteract things. I don't have a Mac to test things on that OS and see if things get extra ugly. I'm not sure either why Magnific is "special" like that. If I were really bored I would investigate further and maybe even submit a pull request. :-)